# Report loading data from client with direct connection, but not from production server

Tags: rdlc

I have am RDLC report + subreport, as part of a WPF program (the data comes from a database, but is passed into the report via EF POCOs). When I run the program on the production server (Windows 8, 64-bit + SQL Server), it appears that no data is being loaded for the report. When I run the program on my machine using the same data (with a remote connection to SQL Server on the production server), the report loads successfully.

Other reports run successfully on both machines.

I've looked at the reporting server logs, and the only thing I could find was the following exception (repeated 3 times):

> Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\ReportServer'.

This is not the issue even if RDLC needs a connection to the remote reporting server somehow, because other reports work fine.

What steps can I take to try and find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved after:

- installing the newest version of the Report Viewer
- updating the .NET Framework version to 4.5.1

Since I did both of these at the same time, I'm not sure which one actually resolved the issue.